# Media Queries is "all" necessary?

Tags: css, media-queries, default

Can I write media queries like this:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
}
```

Or must I do this:

```
@media all and (max-width: 767px) {
}
```

Isn't `all` the default?

Some examples on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) shows media queries without `all`.

Thanks!